# abnormal code execution with Razor

Tags: javascript, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to hide the menus after logging out and pointing to the index page.
I have a layout page that is loaded for each html page.

this is the code:

on logout

```
            $('#Logoutmenu').click(function (e) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
            sessionStorage.setItem("TipoUtente", null);
            sessionStorage.setItem("Utente", null);
            //window.location.href = 'Index';
            $("#Loginmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav hidden").addClass("nav navbar-nav show");
            $("#Logoutmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav show").addClass("nav navbar-nav hidden");
            $("#topmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav show").addClass("nav navbar-nav hidden");

        });
```

this is the document ready code of the layout

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        if (sessionStorage.getItem("Utente") == null) {
            $("#Loginmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav hidden").addClass("nav navbar-nav show");
            $("#Logoutmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav show").addClass("nav navbar-nav hidden");
            $("#topmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav show").addClass("nav navbar-nav hidden");
            }
        else {
            alert("w " + sessionStorage.getItem("Utente"));
            $("#Logoutmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav hidden").addClass("nav navbar-nav show");
            $("#Loginmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav show").addClass("nav navbar-nav hidden");
            $("#topmenu").removeClass("nav navbar-nav hidden").addClass("nav navbar-nav show");
         };

    })
```

despite the result of the statement (sessionStorage.getItem ("User") == null) is true, the execution of the code enters part 'else' !!

if I delete the line of Razor code (`window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';`), the operation is correct !!

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it was enough to replace null with ''. the sessionstorage function stores only strings, comparing a string with null the code was not executed correctly.

@buffjape.
the order of the instructions does not affect.